# How to remove unwanted white space/margin below responsive video

Tags: html, css, video, mobile, responsive

I've got a video and some content below, however when reducing the height of the video on mobile, I'm getting a large amount of white space beneath.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
  video { 
    height: 80%;
    }
```

I could reduce it with margin-bottom etc but I'd rather it was more automated than that for all screen sizes, and I'm pretty sure I just need to wrap the video in a container of sorts and control the complete video/container including h2 etc through there? You can see the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/4v9fk7uq/

Comment: I think `height: 100vh` to `#fashion` is creating the gap.

Answer (score 2):

The `min-height: 100vh` to `#fashion` is causing the gap between the `<main>` and video.

You can decrease the `min-height` of `#fashion` to `80vh`.

Like so -

```css
container {
  position: absolute;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

div#fashion {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Moderne Sans, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: .5rem;
}

h2 {
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Century Schoolbook, Century Schoolbook L, Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 8vmin;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2rem 3rem 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  video {
    height: 80%;
  }
  h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
  }
  div#fashion {
    min-height: 80vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/fashion.jpg" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/fashion.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/fashion.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  <div id="fashion">
    <h2>The new kids on the block.</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<main>
  <h1>example content
  </h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo dolorum totam dicta quidem eaque quos neque, dolor numquam itaque placeat! Id quia at officia, accusamus placeat vero sed ea quo voluptates. Earum praesentium saepe maxime, esse veniam aperiam,
    officiis beatae error voluptatem odit provident optio vel eum nemo, facilis numquam fugit laboriosam. Libero veritatis repellendus quo. Facere perferendis blanditiis, voluptates cupiditate veniam repudiandae cumque sit provident nobis, beatae aut
    aliquam dolorem qui porro repellendus totam animi delectus laudantium.</p>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you swap:

```
 video {
      height: 80%;
   }
```

to

```
video {
          height: 100%;
       }
```

there will be no gaps